# How to display one image out of an array of images 'active-storage'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using **active-storage** for my rails project
I'm wondering how to display the first image of my list of images

[this is how my view looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYjvn.png)

i tried this 

`<%= Ad.first.images.sample %`

it becomes like this
[it becomes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCAh5.png)

is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a relationship like this:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

You could get one like so:

```
Page.first.images.sample
```

Comment: @M.Mannai I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @M.Mannai We need more info than that, I'm afraid. What have you tried and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: i got a blank image

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo that I can take a look at to help further?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

`<% @ads.each do |ad| %>
<%= image_tag(ad.images[0]) if ad.images.length > 0 %>
<% end %>`